# Shell scripting practicing environment.

Tags: linux, unix, linux-mint

I want to learn linux and shell scripting with out installing linux on my machine. I Used linuzoo.com site with provides the environment for practicing but from my machine I could not open the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is - are you asking (1) how to practice or (2) why linuzoo.com is giving you problems?

Regardless, I'd recommend using a virtual machine, instead of any kind of simulator or phony shell. There's no substitute for a real Linux environment. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is an extremely powerful, free, and open-source virtualization environment, so I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you are currently running, I'm assuming Windows.  If so, try Cygwin.  (And if you are on a Mac, you are close enough to Linux -- you can already do shell scripting.)